# how to reuse pom elements across modules

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, reusability

So we have 6 child pom modules with 4 of them sharing common elements for build with few differences that would be parameterized.

So can we have a util pom move these common things and resue across.
I do not want to move to parent, since it is not for all the child modules.

Please suggest if there is a way for this or alternatives. Thanks

Comment: Make an another parent for those 4 children and define the common configuration there ? Which means root with children 1-2, child-parent with children 3-6...

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.

You cannot import parts of POMs. This would be desirable in some cases (I know that) but we probably need to wait for Maven 5.0.0 for that.

What I would recommend:

- Define *all* your plugins and executions in the parent POM.
- Use or define properties to skip them if necessary.
- Override the properties in the modules.

This means

- If your plugin corresponds to property `myplugin.skip` that skips the execution, set this to true in the parent POM and set it to false in all modules that need it.
- If your plugin has a configuration parameter `skip`, but no property, add something like `<skip>${myplugin.skip}</skip>` to the configuration and then use the property `myplugin.skip`.
- Do the same if you have more than one execution of a plugin and you need separate skip parameters.
- If a plugin does not have skip parameter at all (luckily, most plugins have one), you can help yourself by using `<phase>${myplugin.phase}</phase>` and either put `none` or the correct phase in there.

Comment: Sorry, could the downvoter please explain his/her criticism?

Comment: Yes of course. Usage of skip cause sub parents needs different configuration is from my point of view a bad thing. Better make a second level parent into the directory structure and make the appropriate configuration there. Using skip is my experience very bad smell... and often leads to problem which changing later on the modules etc.

Comment: Actually, we used this construction not for multi-module, but in a company POM. I admit that for multi-module, your solution may be better.

Comment: In a company pom I would also not recommend it..cause that means you might need other corporate poms...cause everything which is skipped needs to be turned on somewhere ...which makes handling more complex than needed...

Comment: No, there is just one company POM. It defines all the plugins needed for various types of projects. Some plugins should only run in EJB projects, some only in EARs built for Websphere etc. etc. So each multi-module project inherits from the company POM and then, in the different modules, the necessary plugins are activated by setting the skip property to false.

Comment: We needed to solve the problem that a multi-module project contains of different kinds of modules, but can only have one parent POM. So this parent POM needs to define all the plugins necessary for all possible modules.

Comment: Defining the plugins in pluginManagement means they can be defined and don't need a skip in anyway... If you need special configuration or life cycle bindings you can do that in the appropriate projects which inherit from the parent? ...

Comment: We have 50 EARs in 50 different projects. Should they all copy/paste the `<plugins>` section? We wanted something easy for all the developers who don't know (or don't care) much about Maven. The only two things we found were profiles and skip properties. It is easy to tell the developers "if you build for websphere, set websphere.skip to false", but more difficult to tell them to add a plugin, especially if that plugin has different possible executions.

Comment: @khmarbaise I value your advice, but I want to the average developer to have a most simple configuration, and if I can do this through some properties this definitely shorter and easier to grasp than plugin definitions.